# How can I make it so that it will extract the incrementing variable till it becomes empty?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, extract

```
extract ($wddx_0, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx0");
extract ($wddx_1, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx1");
extract ($wddx_2, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx2");
extract ($wddx_3, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx3");
extract ($wddx_4, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx4");
extract ($wddx_5, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx5");
extract ($wddx_6, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx6");
extract ($wddx_7, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx7");
extract ($wddx_8, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx8");
extract ($wddx_9, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx9");
extract ($wddx_10, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx10");
extract ($wddx_11, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx11");
extract ($wddx_12, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx12");
extract ($wddx_13, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx13");
extract ($wddx_14, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx14");
extract ($wddx_15, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx15");
extract ($wddx_16, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx16");
extract ($wddx_17, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx17");
extract ($wddx_18, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx18");
extract ($wddx_19, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx19");
```

Can this be made dynamic so that it will just keep changing the first and last number until it becomes an empty variable at which time it stops, and runs the next function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; $i<=19; $i++){
    extract(${'wddx_'.$i}, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "wddx".$i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that has worked perfectly, I have never used the "for" function before. I will use that more often now.